# Survival Times for Kaplan Meier Curve

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Kaplan Meier
I am working in R markdown

I would like to know if I am calculating the survival time correct. My data is MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS

My data has the following variables  D_SURGERY (Date of surgery), REV_ARTHROPLASTY (Date of revision),  SENSOR_STATUS ( Which is either 0 = censored or 1 = revised).

The date of revision has dates for the revised cases only. The remaining cells are empty.
[image]

I calculated the survival time in years using the following code:

```
MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS$SURVIVAL_TIME_YEARS = as.numeric(difftime(MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS$REV_ARTHROPLASTY, MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS$D_SURGERY, units = "weeks"))/52.25
```

Then created the curve using the following code:

```
survfit2(Surv(SURVIVAL_TIME_YEARS, CENSOR_STATUS) ~ 1, data = MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS) %>% 
  ggsurvfit() +
  labs(
    x = "Years",
    y = "Overall Survival Probability"
  )+ 
  add_confidence_interval()+
  add_risktable()
```

Then I want to see the survival at 10 years and used the following code:

```
summary(survfit(Surv(SURVIVAL_TIME_YEARS, CENSOR_STATUS) ~ 1, data = MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS), times = 10)
```

And I had the following results
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(SURVIVAL_TIME_YEARS, CENSOR_STATUS) ~
1, data = MOWHTO_COMPLICATIONS)

678 observations deleted due to missingness
time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI
10      8      55    0.127  0.0419       0.0665
upper 95% CI
0.243

So, the survival is 0.127  that is 13% at 10 years. It can not be correct. It should be over 80 or 90%?

What am I doing wrong? Is it the survival time? Should I have dates for the cases that is not revised? And what dates should be?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty columns need to have a date in it or when you take the difftime, the result will be empty.

For example:

```
as.numeric(difftime(ISOdate(2001, 4, 26), NA, units = "weeks"))/52.25
```

returns NA

Instead fill in the last date the subject was observed when the event of interest did not occur. That way when you subtract the dates, you will get a value for time.

There is a hint in this part of the output:

> 678 observations deleted due to missingness time

They deleted those records because they didn't have a time value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The column that does have the empty celle is the REV_ARTHROPLASTY column, where few celle have the date of the event of interest ( revision). How do I fill up the rest of the empty cells with a date if I followed up all patients up to 5 years from date of surgery. What code to use? Especially without affecting the celle that have the revision date for the few cases that were revised.

Comment: You could create another column using a case_when statement from the dplyr library.

`df %>% mutate(end_date = dplyr::case_when(REV_ARTHROPLASTY == "" ~ "01/01/2023", TRUE ~ REV_ARTHROPLASTY)`

but choose the end date you want to use instead of 01/01/2023.

Comment: This also assumes that the value inside the REV_ARTHROPLASTY column is empty "" when it isn't filled. If that isn't true, then use whatever makes that true.